# Python Pandas string replace time values not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of times in string format. I want to replace values in but it is not working. I feel like I am missing something simple. What is it?

Code

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(["08:05:00", "08:15:00", "08:25:00", "08:55:00", "09:05:00", "09:15:00", "09:25:00"])
print(s.dtype)
s.replace({"07:": "7:", "08:": "8:", "09:": "9:"}, inplace=True)
```

The output I get is.

```
object
0    08:05:00
1    08:15:00
2    08:25:00
3    08:55:00
4    09:05:00
5    09:15:00
6    09:25:00
dtype: object
```

what I want is:

```
0    8:05:00
1    8:15:00
2    8:25:00
3    8:55:00
4    9:05:00
5    9:15:00
6    9:25:00
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
s.str.lstrip('0')
```

O/P;;

```
0    8:05:00
1    8:15:00
2    8:25:00
3    8:55:00
4    9:05:00
5    9:15:00
6    9:25:00
dtype: object
```

`lstrip` docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which is in the `s.replace` line of code. Since the desire is to find beginning character of `0` then use of regex is better. The replacement line of code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(["08:05:00", "08:15:00", "08:25:00", "08:55:00", "09:05:00", "09:15:00", "09:25:00"])
print(s.dtype)
s.replace({"^0": ""}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```